# Is it possible to get sharepoint context through moles in moss 2007?

Tags: unit-testing, sharepoint-2007

My project is created in moss 2007 with VSTS 2008. Now we are planning to automate unit testing,
Is it possible to get sharepoint context through moles in moss 2007? because we are not able to get any sharepoint object in unite testing.

Thanks
Saurabh